# Activate SWFUpload trigger with plain anchor

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, swfupload

This might be a simple question with a simple fix, but I am unable to figure out the solution.

I am using SWFUpload on a site to facilitate file uploads (obviously), however, it requires placing a placeholder using a span or something of the likes:

```
<span id="SWF_Placeholder_etc"></span>
```

And then calling SWFUpload which essentially replaces that span with:

```
<object id="SWFUpload_1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/swfupload/Flash/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1365470153721" width="120" height="35" class="swfupload">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  <param name="movie" value="/swfupload/Flash/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1365470153721">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="flashvars" value="all settings in here">
</object>
```

This requires passing all kinds of flash vars using a clunky image with various rollover/activity states of the button in it in order to 'style' it, and I use the term 'style' **very** loosely.

I want to basically have a hidden flash object, that I can activate using a javascript call to flash to either trigger the click (which I do not think will work, due to security reasons) or have some call into SWFUpload's code to actually trigger the action - using a nice, easy to style `<a>` tag.

Anyone? I cannot be the first person that has ever wanted to do this, I just hope that someone else has found some success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
SWFUpload.instances.SWFUpload_0.selectFiles() or selectFile()
```

but unfortunately it's not supported in Flash 10 +
What I would do is just make an HTML element, Style it, and serve it as the button text image